# Jquery positioning dynamic div scrolltop

Tags: jquery, html, positioning

I have a two column webpage. the first(id="#list") is a list of divs and it can get longer with content. The second(id="#expand") is an expanded view, when a div is clicked on the left column. Imagine twitter like layout, with a new column on the right side.

Users keep scrolling down to see left div. When they click on any one of that divs,

1. how can I position the right ("#expand") div in the viewing area. ?
2. If they scroll down, "#expand" should behave normal, as in it should be where it is.
3. If they scroll up, "#expand" should move up, until hitting the top.

Can someone help? NOTE: #expand is DYNAMIC, brought in via AJAX

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link that can demo the request?

Comment: I tried
var position = $('#expand')[0].scrollTop;
       
       if(position<200)
       {
       $('#expand').animate({ scrollTop: 200 }, 'slow');
       }

I am learning jquery, sorry if I am totally off.

Comment: @malkassem I am working on my local machine. I will try to bring up a demo page soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to switch between `position: fixed, top: 0` and `position: absolute, top: <the current scroll position>` as the user scrolls past the "top" of the #expand element. The code below uses a (not quite) global variable to track where this switch should occur. You could use `$("#expand").data(...)` or something else if you prefer, but you get the idea.

```
(function () {
var expandY = 0;
$("a[name=somelink]").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Keep from following link.
    expandY = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("#expand").css({position: "fixed", top: 0});
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var $expand = $("#expand");
    if($expand.css("position") === "fixed") {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > expandY) {
            $expand.css({position: "absolute", top: expandY});
        }
    }
    else {
        if($(window).scrollTop() < expandY) {
            $expand.css({position: "fixed", top: 0});
        }
    }
});

})();
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rkp5x/3

Answer (score 1):

Try using fixed positioning, that will keep it on the same place in the page:

```
#expand{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: But if #expand is bigger than window, then it wont scroll if i use fixed. right?

Comment: @aVC Add an `overflow: auto` to it ;-)